# Google play services on Visual Studio Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, xamarin.forms, google-play-services, visual-studio-emulator

I am trying to install Google play services. 
I followed this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/.

I have the play store icon. But when I click on it a splash screen appears and goes away. When I run my app, which has geolocator, I still get a message saying, it won't run without Google Play Services, which are missing from your phone. How do I see what the problem is?

Comment: Use the Google HAXM emulator if you can, easiest way to have access to Google Play services

Comment: in comment

Try to follow the steps here in this [thread](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/10/28/installing-google-play-services-gapps-on-visual-studio-android-emulators/) on how to install Google Play Service on Visual Studio Android Emulators. This thread also includes an update dated Feb 2017. So just follow the steps here and check if it works in your case.